# Sharing data with custom canvas view

Tags: android, canvas

I'm a beginner at android programming, so excuse me if my wording is slightly incorrect.

I have a custom canvas view along with a TextView inside a linear layout, defined in the layout file as

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/blah"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" 
/>        
<com.*.Overlay android:id="@+id/combined"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"           
/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I need to be able to read the text contained in the TextView from within the Overlay custom class that I created.
(The overlay class takes in 2 bitmaps and puts one on top of the other. The bitmaps used will depend on the text in the TextView.)

I considered using intents, but the Overlay class doesn't have an onCreate method.. All my code is within the onDraw method. I also added the necessary constructors.

I'm not sure what to try next, perhaps try accessing the parent linearlayout and then its child textview?

Hope I managed to explain everything in a non-confusing manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to fix the issue... sort of
I found out that Views need to be contained in Activities.. so I created a new Activity with my custom view as an inner class, passed an intent with the necessary data to the activity and was able to use it successfully in my custom canvas view.

I was a bit surprised I didn't get any responses, but I guess that's because I'm new here